# IndexError: list assignment index out of range (in __init__)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Due to my recent interest in Information Security and network programming, I've decided to learn Python through the Internet. I'm trying to write a piece of code which would allow the user to store the Biodata(name, age and job) of the desired number of people. And then the O/P would consist of the biodata of all of those people along with the people count. Being new to Python, I'm not able to identify the error.
Thanks - Sid

Here's my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    class Bio:
        counts = 0
        myBio = []
        def __init__(self, name, age, job):
            Bio.myBio[Bio.counts] = name
            Bio.myBio[Bio.counts+1] = age
            Bio.myBio[Bio.counts+2] = job
            Bio.counts + 1
        def display(self):
            for myBio in range(0, Bio.counts):
                    print myBio
    while 1:
        name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
        age = int(raw_input("Enter your age: "))
        job  = raw_input("Enter your Job: ")
        details = Bio(name, age, job)
        details.display()
        print "Detail Count %d" % Bio.myBio
        anymore = raw_input("Anymore details ?: (y/n)")
        if anymore == 'n':
            break
```

Here's the trace of my O/P:

```
   ./bio.py
   Enter your name: Sid
   Enter your age: 21
   Enter your Job: InfoSec
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./bio.py", line 25, in <module>
   details = Bio(name, age, job)
   File "./bio.py", line 9, in __init__
   Bio.myBio[Bio.counts] = name
   IndexError: list assignment index out of range*
```

Comment: Your code has a number of problems.  You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with the basics of Python.

Comment: There isn't really a good reason to use a list for this. Plain attributes, or a `dict`, if you have some desperate need for another data structure, would be more appropriate. Also note that `counts` and `myBio` are *class variables*, not *instance variables*, which probably isn't what you want. It means they are the same for all instances. Make them in `__init__()` instead.

Comment: You know, when you type in a title when asking a question, you get a list of similar questions. In this case the list of questions with your exact error is *long* and reading *any* of those questions would have answered your question, and been quicker too. Try that next time.

Comment: @LennartRegebro you forgot to mention they are also listed on the right under 'Related' :)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Sure, but that's *after* the question was posted. The list above is *before* you post it.

Comment: Alright I apologize. And thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
class Bio:

    def __init__(self, name, age, job):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.job = job
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably what you are looking for is:

```
def __init__(self, name, age, job):
    Bio.myBio.append(name)
    Bio.myBio.append(age)
    Bio.myBio.append(job)
    Bio.counts + 1
```

The problem is that the elements `Bio.counts`, `Bio.counts+1`, and `Bio.counts+2` don't exist when you create the class; you have to create them with the `append` method.

**NOTE**

You probably don't need the `Bio.counts` variable.  You can rewrite `display` as

```
def display(self):
    for myBio in Bio.myBio:
        print myBio
```

You also probably want to think about why you are using `Bio`instead of `self`.

Comment: It more likely is `Bio.myBio.append([name,age,job])`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Agreed.  The OP probably wants to significantly rethink their data structure.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?  If I didn't answer the question I can update.